# PIL module was not found in Thonny

Tags: command-line, python

I can not use PIL module in Thonny IDE.

from PIL import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Interesting part is that I can find PIL module in Python Shell but not in Thonny. By the way my OS is Ubuntu. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you install Thonny? With `apt`, `pip` or as Thonny+Python bundle? If latter, then it doesn't use system Python packages.